# executing jar in browser

Tags: java, encryption, executable-jar

When I am executing a jar file from the browser, is the class file running on the `client end` or `on the server end`?

I am developing a security web application where `files are encrypted and decrypted`. I need this to be done on the client side through a pin which client chooses.

Therefore when an jar file is running on the browser, `is the class file` where encryption and decryption is done `processes on the client end or in the server end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the jar file with jnlp ( Webstart) but it will not run on browser. Only a launch. You can execute code In Applet / JApplet, which will be in browser. Depends what you need at business logic.

Answer (score 0):

mostly as matheszabi mentioned what business demands.
you are not executing jar anytime in client end. Via Applet/JApplet you are loading the byte source into browser which then executes your actions. For this you need to have java run time to be installed on the client machine for browser support.

if you are using jsp/servlet model you would understand the java execution is always on the server side.

Comment: I understand the working of jsp/servlet which runs on the server side. when I launch a jar application on the browser, which runs on the browser provided java runtime environment is installed on the client machine, will the methods of the class and functions run on the client or to the server side ?????. I am asking since, I need to encrypt the file using the provided pin on the client side and den upload the file to the server. I am developing a web application or a website which delivers secure storage of files on server.

Comment: then the question should be how are you executing the jar. >> Could you please elaborate. >> How are you launching a jar application on browser.  >> In jsp/servlet server returns only HTML forms or pages.